# click any li, know which one, do something accordingly

Tags: jquery, list

Ok, so I know how to get all the li items and indices, such as:

```
totalLi = $('.content li').length;
clck = $('li.content).index();
```

and writing something to allow clicking of any li, such as:
    $('.content li').click(function() {something})

and yet I can't seem to figure out how I would:
"Click on any li in a given list, identify which it is, and based on that send a parameter to a function that would animate something else."

The part I'm stuck on is that by using:
    #('.content li').click.... I don't know how to pull the index value with a variable. I'm all over the place with "this" but alerting that only gets [object] returned so it's to generic.

I'm guessing I should set the index to a variable but maybe not?

I'm wanting to have a dynamic routine so that whether there are 5 or 15 li's, I can click on any of them and make something happen. The snapper is that I need to have a previous and next item. I can get those to appear easy enough, but iterating +1 or -1 seems like it would interfere with the li's that are a, b, c, d etc. (instead of numbers, either way the list is just a navigation to go through the questions but any number could be clicked on... it's not linear)

I've played with .each() and first/end etc.. I'm not getting it?

Comment: Can you post simplified HTML that demonstrates what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.content li').click(function(){ 
    var ind = $(this).index();
})
```

is this not working?

`$('.content li').click()` binds the click event on each li element. Then when you refer to `$(this)` it will direct to the element which has triggered the click event and you can directly use that element. It is up to you what you want : index(), text(), html() or any other attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

http://jsfiddle.net/TRUYd/

Answer (score 1):

you should be using/assigning id's to each of your li elements so that for you to determine which specific element is being clicked. Very much like on Dejan.S example.

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">..</li>
  <li id="2">..</li>
  <li id="3">..
</ul>
```

---

```
$('li').click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 1: alert('you clicked li #1'); break;
        case 2: ...do something else
        case 3: ...do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, on my smaller list, I have done this but it isn't too dynamic. In the future for larger lists, I would have to add new case statements manually, however there is some insight here with how you set-up the switch so thanks! (I can't yet 'vote-up')

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value from the current clicked with `$(this)` wich indicated this current element that you just clicked

check out this sample http://jsfiddle.net/TKPNt/

```
<ul id="list">
<li id="1">value 1</li>
<li id="2">value 2</li>
</ul>

$('#list li').click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
});​
​
```

you can say if you need more assistance

Comment: This also helps me in other areas but it is not as dynamic as I'm looking for.... if I explicitly write code to address specific id's that means I would have to add those id's in future lists, however, as above it's helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this...

http://jsfiddle.net/TKPNt/2/

Comment: I think my issue now is using 'this' inside of an if statement. 
It appears this doesn't work: 
    $('#list li').click(function(){
    var moby = this.index(); 
     if(moby == 1){ 
        $(moby).addClass('current'); 
                  }
       });

Comment: You are making a mistake here its not this.index() it should be $(this).index(); please make the change and let me know.

Comment: hmm.. this still is not working..I've got: $('#list li').click(function(){
    var moby = $(this).index(); 
    if(moby == 1){
        $(moby).addClass('current');
    }
});